# Using services in Doctrine repositories

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How would I inject services in Doctrine repositories? Is it a good idea to do so? Should I make a doctrine repository container aware or should I pass services in the function arguments?

For example: I want to use a service called "knp_pager" that paginates queries. I want to have it available in the getArticleList() function of my Article repository so that I can return a paged result.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, inject the `knp_pager` service into your repository is not a good idea. It's not the responsability of the repository to paginate your query.

For limiting your query, I would pass an optional `offset` & an optional `length` to the repository method which can be generated by the `knp_pager`. Like that, the repository responsability is respected and you are able to limit your query easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can define services from your repository, there is a cookbook recipe on symfony 2 website about that. Then you can inject other services using setters and wiring them in the container configuration.

Anyway I would try to keep repository classes as simple as possible (let's say that they should only provide generic data access) and inject them in other services if I need more abstraction on complex operations.